# Return all array values with ACF fields and foreach loop

Tags: arrays, wordpress, foreach, advanced-custom-fields, acfpro

I created a checkbox field in ACF and want to loop this field again and again and show all these values. First I tried it the way the ACF documentation shows, but the following code results in just the value of the first checked checkbox.

```
function ms_get_department(){
    $departments = get_field('vakgebied');
    
    if($departments):
        foreach($departments as $department):
            echo '<span class="department-text">' . $department['label'] . '</span>';
        endforeach;
    endif;
}
```

I also tried to store all the values inside an array but in the code below it just shows 'Array' and don't know how to show all these data in this case.

```
function ms_get_department(){
    $departments = get_field('vakgebied');
    $deps = array();
    
    if($departments):
        foreach($departments as $department):
            $deps[] = $department['label'];
            // $test = '<span class="department-text">' . $department['label'] . '</span>';
            
        endforeach;

        return $deps;

    
    endif;
}
```

Does anyone know how I can solve this problem in a proper way?

Comment: Try to `print_r($deps);`

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear where you're adding this function. If it's on the single page then the code should work; however, if it's on any other page then you'd need to pass the post ID to ACF Field.

```
function ms_get_department(){
$departments = get_field('vakgebied', 123); // 123 being the post ID
$deps = array();

if($departments):
    foreach($departments as $department):
        $deps[] = $department['label'];
        // $test = '<span class="department-text">' . $department['label'] . '</span>';
        
    endforeach;

    return $deps;


endif;
```

}

Another thing to check is, make sure ACF field is returning both 'label' and 'value'.

Comment: I use this in a shortcode that I place on a archive-page and a single, but both won't work. Also is the ACF field returning both label and value